# PyQt Push Button randomly stops working in PyQGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I keep running into a very weird issue with `clicked.connect` not working in various plugins I am working on. The error happens randomly in QGIS 3.x versions and it seems to happen on some machines only.

It is very hard to research this online and I am not sure if it is linked to QGIS or to PyQt or to a combination thereof.

What happens: I click a push button but the method that has been connected to it just does not trigger (**even though it has triggered many, many times before**).

The only fix I found so far (after hours of trying the most random things): I intentionally insert an error that does not break the plugin on reload but only once the GUI is opened and the handlers are connected.

Workflow:

My button (`btnAddShapefile`) stops working (i.e. the method `addShapefileToQgis` is just not called when clicking the button)

```
self.btnAddShapefile.clicked.connect(self.addShapefileToQgis)
```

Now I change the method to a method that does not exist, e.g.:

```
self.btnAddShapefile.clicked.connect(self.HELLO)
```

Now I reload the plugin and open it again. The plugin then crashes, because:

```
AttributeError: 'UploadData' object has no attribute 'HELLO'
```

(UploadData is the name of the class)

Now I fix the error, i.e. I revert to the method that actually exists:

```
self.btnAddShapefile.clicked.connect(self.addShapefileToQgis)
```

Now I reload the plugin, open it again, click the button, and the method is called without any issues.

I am absolutely clueless why this happens in the first place and why an intentional error that breaks the plugin actually helps me fix it.

Comment: When you say change, do you mean you disconnect the other method first?

Comment: @bugmenot123 By change I mean that instead of using a method that actually exists (i.e. addShapefileToQgis) I mention some random method that does not exist (HELLO). The plugin then breaks because the button cannot connect to that "method".

Comment: Does it work if you always remove the __pycache__ directory/-ies in your plugin's directory?

Comment: This does not fix it. I can delete the pycache directory, then reload the plugin, but the buttons still won't work. I also wondered if it is linked to some caching issue.

Comment: Could you add a minimal (not) working example? We don't know the structure of your plugin script. Where do you run the `connect` line?

Comment: More or less agree about `connect` position. Issue could be about repeated `connect` declaration execution instead of once but could be totally wrong.

Comment: The connect line is in the __init__ method of a class. It is not in the main plugin class (i.e. the one that has initGui etc.) but a separate class. I do not have access to the code right now, but I will edit the question with an example as soon as I can access it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @BritishSteel ? I'm facing the same problem at the moment